# How to fix maximum and minimum for X and Y axis in angular Chart using Chart.js - Bar and Line Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

As shown in picture, the maximum value is 4.

[image]

```
   $scope.chartParams = {

    listOfLocations: ['Trenzalore', 'Earth', 'Caprica', 'Sol', 'Tau Ceti'],

    series: ["Nice Places"],
    colours: [{ fillColor: color }],
    options: {
        //barShowStroke: false,

    },

    votes: [[4, 2, 1, 2, 3]]
};
});
```

This is the JS code written using Angular.

Below is the HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="BarCtrl">
    <canvas id="stacked" 
class="chart chart-bar" 
data="chartParams.votes"
 labels="chartParams.listOfLocations"
 series="chartParams.series" 
colours="chartParams.colours" 
options="chartParams.options"></canvas>
  </div>
```

How to fix Maximum y-axis limit as 5, and minimum value as 0.?

Answer (score 0):

Define your options like this

```
options: {
        //barShowStroke: false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{id: 'y-axis-1', ticks: {min: 0, max:5}}]
      }
    },
```

This will limit your yAxe from 0 to 5.

Comment: Hi, tried that also, it didn't work. Still max value is at 4.

Comment: try setting max:6 so it may let you reach max to 5